# Grouping items before a certain date

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("""TitleCode,ReleaseDate,WeekEnding,TotalUnits
A,12/16/2017,12/2/2017 0:00,5
A,12/16/2017,12/9/2017 0:00,10
A,12/16/2017,12/16/2017 0:00,2
A,12/16/2017,12/23/2017 0:00,5
A,12/16/2017,12/30/2017 0:00,4
B,1/6/2018,1/13/2017 0:00,4
B,1/6/2018,1/20/2017 0:00,2
""")


result = StringIO("""TitleCode,ReleaseDate,WeekEnding,TotalUnits
A,12/16/2017,12/16/2017 0:00,17
A,12/16/2017,12/23/2017 0:00,5
A,12/16/2017,12/30/2017 0:00,4
B,1/6/2018,1/13/2017 0:00,4
B,1/6/2018,1/13/2017 0:00,2
""")
datadf = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=True)
resultdf = pd.read_csv(result, parse_dates=True)

datadf
    TitleCode   ReleaseDate WeekEnding  TotalUnits
0   A   12/16/2017  12/2/2017 0:00  5
1   A   12/16/2017  12/9/2017 0:00  10
2   A   12/16/2017  12/16/2017 0:00 2
3   A   12/16/2017  12/23/2017 0:00 5
4   A   12/16/2017  12/30/2017 0:00 4
5   B   1/6/2018    1/13/2017 0:00  4
6   B   1/6/2018    1/13/2017 0:00  2

resultdf
    TitleCode   ReleaseDate WeekEnding  TotalUnits
0   A   12/16/2017  12/16/2017 0:00 17
1   A   12/16/2017  12/23/2017 0:00 5
2   A   12/16/2017  12/30/2017 0:00 4
3   B   1/6/2018    1/13/2017 0:00  4
4   B   1/6/2018    1/20/2017 0:00  2
```

The datadf dataframe shows item sales by week, and the release date of the item. I want to group together all pre-sell sales, that is, sales that occur before the release date (resultdf).

The only way I can think of doing it is by looping over the dataframe but there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# standardize datetime format for comparison
datadf['WeekEnding'] = pd.to_datetime(datadf.WeekEnding, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
datadf['ReleaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(datadf.ReleaseDate, format='%m/%d/%Y')

# replace weekending with release date if smaller
datadf['WeekEnding'] = datadf['WeekEnding'].where(
    datadf['WeekEnding'] > datadf['ReleaseDate'], datadf['ReleaseDate']
)

datadf.groupby(
    ['TitleCode', 'ReleaseDate', 'WeekEnding']
).TotalUnits.sum().reset_index()
```

[image]